# Removing Negative Numbers from a list Python using while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, negative-number

`rmNegative(L)` removes the negative numbers from `list L`, assumed to contain only numeric elements. (Modifies L; does not create a new list.)

How would I go about this when using a while loop? I've tried coding it over and over and all I got was a never ending loop..

```
def rmNegatives(L):
    pos=len(L)-1
    while pos>-1:
        pos=pos
        if pos<len(L)-1:
            pos=pos
            if L[pos]>0:
                L[:]=L[:]
                pos=len(L)-2
            elif L[pos]<0:
                L[:]=[L[pos]]+L[0:]
                L[:]=L[1:]
                pos=len(L)-1

        elif pos==len(L)-1:
            pos=pos
            if L[pos]<0:
                L[0:]=L[0:pos]
                pos=len(L)-1
            elif L[pos]>0:
                L[:]=L[:]
                pos=len(L)-2

rmNegatives([-25,31,-10,23,45,-2])
```

[Run the code here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code='''%0A++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3Apos%5D%0A++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++++++++++if+L%5Bpos%5D%3C0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3Apos%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-2%0A++++++++++++if+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-3%0A++++++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3C0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3D%5BL%5Bpos%5D%5D%2BL%5B0%3Apos%5D%0Adef+rmNegatives(L)%3A%0A++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++while+pos%3E-1%3A%23what+to+change+this+to.%0A++++++++if+L%5Bpos%5D%3C0%3A%0A++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3D%5BL%5Bpos%5D%5D%2BL%5B0%3Apos%5D%0A++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++++++++++if+L%5Bpos%5D%3C0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3D%5BL%5Bpos%5D%5D%2BL%5B0%3Apos%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos-len(L)-1%0A++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++++++++++if+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-3%0A++++++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3C0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3D%5BL%5Bpos%5D%5D%2BL%5B0%3Apos%5D%0A++++++++++++pos-%3D1'''%0Adef+rmNegatives(L)%3A%0A++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++while+pos%3E-1%3A%0A++++++++pos%3Dpos%0A++++++++if+pos%3Clen(L)-1%3A%0A++++++++++++pos%3Dpos%0A++++++++++++if+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B%3A%5D%3DL%5B%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-2%0A++++++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3C0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B%3A%5D%3D%5BL%5Bpos%5D%5D%2BL%5B0%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B%3A%5D%3DL%5B1%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++++++++++%0A++++++++elif+pos%3D%3Dlen(L)-1%3A%0A++++++++++++pos%3Dpos%0A++++++++++++if+L%5Bpos%5D%3C0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B0%3A%5D%3DL%5B0%3Apos%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-1%0A++++++++++++elif+L%5Bpos%5D%3E0%3A%0A++++++++++++++++L%5B%3A%5D%3DL%5B%3A%5D%0A++++++++++++++++pos%3Dlen(L)-2%0A++++++++++++%0ArmNegatives(%5B-25,31,-10,23,45,-2%5D)%0A++++++++++++%0A++++++++++++%0A++++++++++++++++&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

edit** i thank you for your responses. the reason why my code does not contain any form of remove or index is because i was restricted from using them(would have been nice if they weren't but..)

Comment: Your list doesn't work for me, shows me no code. You can just put your code in your post.

Comment: I edited it pending approval of course.

Comment: Looks like the first block is a comment? I missed the `'''` on my first edit. Maybe it's best showing just the code that will run?

Comment: Do you want us to debug your existing code? I'm really not sure what most of it is _trying_ to do, so it's hard to say where it's going wrong. For example, what did you expect `pos = pos` or `L[:] = L[:]` to do? Why `pos=len(L)-2`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation with a while loop.  I start at the end because the list is getting shorter as the loop iterates and the earlier indexes are shifting as a result.

```
def rmNegative(L):
    index = len(L) - 1
    while index >= 0:
        if L[index] < 0:
            del L[index]
        index = index - 1
```

Comment: Starting at the end means you don't need to keep checking `len`. Not using `remove` means not teaching bad habits (and not incurring quadratic performance). But… you're starting with `L[len(L)]` instead of `L[len(L)-1]`, which is an `IndexError`.  And that `- 4` instead of `- 1` can't be a good idea.

Comment: @abarnert That's what I get for retyping something that I have in another window.  I don't know how I typoed the -4.  That certainly wasn't intended.  Thanks for catching those.  I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot afford to create a new list and you have to use a `while` loop:

```
l = [1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5]
x = 0
while x < len(l):
  if l[x] < 0:
    l.remove(l[x])
    continue
  x += 1
```

Alternatively, as suggested by abarnert (lower runtime):

```
l = [1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5]
x = 0
while x < len(l):
  if l[x] < 0:
    del l[x]
    continue
  x += 1
```

If you absolutely cannot afford to create a new list, but can use a `for` loop:

```
l = [1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5]
for x in xrange(len(l)):
  if x < len(l) and l[x] < 0:
    l.remove(l[x])
```

If you can afford to create a new list:

```
l = [1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5]
l = [num for num in l if num >= 0]
```

Comment: Using `remove` is a bad idea. It does sort of work here, because it doesn't really matter if you remove the "wrong" `-1`, because you're ultimately going to remove all of them anyway. But it's still a bad habit to learn. Not to mention giving quadratic performance instead of linear for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

The first think you need to know is that `del L[i]` removes the `i`th element. (Don't use `L.remove(L[i])`; that looks up the `i`th element, then searches the whole list until it finds an equal value, then deletes that.)

But notice that if you delete `L[3]`, and then move on to `L[4]`, you've skipped one value—the original `L[4]` is now `L[3]`, and you still need to check it. So you have to make sure not to increment `i` until you find a value that you're keeping.

But if you just loop over all of the indices, and you've deleted some along the way, you're going to run off the end. So, you need to decrement the the length every time you delete. Or you could also just keep calling `len(L)` again and checking against the new length each time.

One clever way to solve both of those problems at once is to count backward, as in [Brad Budlong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29691617/908494). But that can make it easy to make fencepost errors. So, I'll do it the other way.

```
def rmNegative(L):
    length = len(L)
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        if L[i] < 0:
            del L[i]
            length -= 1
        else:
            i += 1
```

And that's it.

---

If you want to know why your existing code is an infinite loop, let's step through a bit of what it does.

We start with `pos=len(L)-1`, so we go into the big `elif`. `pos=pos` does nothing. If it's a negative number, you remove it and go to the new `len(L)-1`; if it's a positive number, you leave it, and go to `len(L)-2`. If it's 0, we do neither, which means `pos=len(L)-1` still, and we're just going to repeatedly look at that 0 forever.

So, that's one way to get an infinite loop. But let's assume it didn't end in 0.

If we've just removed a negative number, we go back to the `elif`, and we know that's OK unless 0.

But if we've left a positive number, then we now have `pos=len(L)-2`, so we go to the `if`. Again, `pos=pos` does nothing. If it's a positive number, we copy the list to itself, which does nothing, then set `pos=len(L)-2`. Which is the same thing it already is. So, if the next-to-last number is positive, we're just going to keep looking at that number forever. That's another way to get an infinite loop.

What if it was negative? Then `L[:]=[L[pos]]+L[0:]` prepends the value you wanted to delete to the whole list (which still includes the original copy of the value), `L[:]=L[1:]` removes the value you just prepended, so you end up with the same values in `L` you started with. Then you set `pos=len(L)-1`, which goes back to the end of the list. We know that's going to work successfully, and get back to the next-to-last slot again, which will still be the same value, so we'll shuttle back and forth forever. So, that's enough way to get an infinite loop.

What if it was 0? Then we do nothing, so `pos` and `L` never change, so that's another way to get an infinite loop.

So, once we get a positive element on the end of the list, all three possibilities for the next-to-last element are infinite loops.

Stepping back a bit, the only things your code ever sets `pos` to are `len(L)-1` and `len(L)-2`. So, even if you did all of the others stuff right, how could this possibly ever complete on a list with more than 2 non-negative numbers?

Comment: Subtracting 1 from length solves the problem of running off the end, but you have the problem that if you have two negative numbers in a row, you will miss the second one.  That is because you delete item i and move onto item i+1, but the delete moved the next item down to index i and you don't check it.  You need to put the `i += 1` into an else to fix this.

Comment: @BradBudlong: No I don't. Notice that the `i += 1` only happens in the `else`. Also notice that there's a whole paragraph explaining that.

Comment: I was commenting about your original version that didn't solve and explain the problem.

Comment: @BradBudlong: The else was there in the first version, although I did have an indent error which I fixed, and lots of typos in the text, and, worst of all, `length - 1` instead of `length -= 1`. At any rate, your comment is only 5 minutes ago, and you can see the version from 8 minutes ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29691759/revisions), which already had all of those fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def rmNegatives(L):
    i = 0
    while i < len(L):
        if L[i] < 0:
            L.pop(i)
        else:
            i += 1
    return L
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation of `rmNegative(L)`.

```
def rmNegative(L):
    m = min(L)
    while m < 0:
        L.remove(m)
        m = min(L)
```

This modifies the list and does not create a new list.

Answer (score -2):

Well, not allocating new list now,

```
>>> list_l = [1, -1, 2, -8]

>>> length = len(list_l)
>>> while i < length:
...     if list_l[i] < 0:
...             del list_l[i]
...             length -= 1
...     else:
...             i = i + 1
... 
>>> list_l
[1, 2]
```

Comment: This creates a new list and overwrites the old reference. Using a loop is probably part of the lesson.

Comment: Please, kindly tell me now, what I've faltered in to deserve a down-vote.

Comment: @pnv: Usually people who downvote without comments never come back and look again after you edit. So, even if TigerhawkT3 undid his downvote (I don't know if he did…), you're probably not going to get the other 2 back. And I wouldn't expect to get too many upvotes, because your new correct version doesn't add anything that wasn't already in any other answers. So if you're really worried about the rep, you may want to just delete the answer.

Comment: Point noted, but definitely not gonna delete this. :)